# how to connect javascript to elements added after the html code is updated?

Tags: javascript, dom, code-injection, queryselector

I am following the Dom javascript net ninja series, and I am stuck because after I inject an 'li' element the delete function doesn't work anymore. I had a similar problem at first, the querySelector() method didn't work, but it was solved using setTimeout(), can u help, please?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="cont.js"></script>
    <title>Testing JavaScript</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        <div id="page-banner">
          <h1 class="title">My Contacts</h1>
          <p>Special List</p>
          <form id="search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search Contacts..." />
          </form>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div id="Contact-List">
        <h2 class="title">Contacts</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span class="contat">Zineb Zrhari</span>
            <span class="delete">delete</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="contat">Kawter Lebouni</span>
            <span class="delete">delete</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="contat">Oumayma Touji</span>
            <span class="delete">delete</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="contat">Rim Essahel</span>
            <span class="delete">delete</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <form id="add">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add a Contact..." />
        <button>Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the javascript code:

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
  const list = document.querySelector("#Contact-List ul");

  // delete books
  list.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.className == "delete") {
      const li = e.target.parentElement;
      li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
    }
  });

  // add book
  const addForm = document.forms["add"];
  addForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const value = addForm.querySelector("input[type='text']").value;

    // create elements
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    const contact = document.createElement("span");
    const deleteBtn = document.createElement("span");

    // add contant
    deleteBtn.textContent = "delete";
    deleteBtn.classList.add("delete");
    contact.textContent = value;
    deleteBtn.classList.add("name");

    // append to document
    li.appendChild(contact);
    li.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    list.appendChild(li);
  });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need `setTimeout`?

Comment: because when I didn't it didn't work at all.

Comment: I run your example in my local, correcting the error related to `deleteBtn.classList.add(" name");` I have deleted `setTimeout` and the application is running fine fine

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting your complete code.

The issue is with this line of your JavaScript:

```
if(e.target.className == 'delete'){
```

This will work if `delete` is the only class applied to an element. However, you are applying two classes to the new element, which means `e.target.className` becomes `delete name`.

You can fix it by changing the line to:

```
if(e.target.classList.includes('delete')) {
```

This will work even if the element has multiple classes.

Comment: Tath's it, actually i just realized it, thank u very much